# Debugging App engine with golang -- There has to be a better way?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I"m (slowly) working on a app-engine app using the go language -- While I like many parts of the experience (the nice integration with google services and the go language itself) but I'm a bit suprised at the lack of debug facilities especially with app engine.

I know that you can log to the console (The lowest form of debugging IMHO) but all attempts at anything more clever (attaching gdb on the local instance) fails. (the build tools for app engine specifically seem to strip debug info)

I can't believe I'm the only one who has observed this so I'm wondering what other folks are doing to develop/debug in app engine?

Comment: This isn't really an answer, but it's worth noting that most people do Go development w/o a debugger. That's not to say that it /should/ be done that way, but the lack of debugger support (aside from GDB) hasn't seemed to be a big problem for people, probably because Go development is just so pleasant and straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

There is not currently a better way than `context.Errorf()` and friends. Python [just got](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-appengine/ep5BWYKpQpU/41asdxKhuycJ) `pdb` support in the 1.8.3 SDK. I have not heard of any similar debugger support for go. It is perhaps worth asking on the app engine go list about this.

Answer (score 2):

I just red about your topic in this blog:

http://joshua.themarshians.com/hardcore-google-unit-testing.html

I can't give you an example but maybe it will help.

Comment: thanks -- that post is perhaps the best solution I've seen so far.

Answer (score 0):

it's been an update and I thought to add what is the current state of affair.

The good news is the go tools now no longer strip debug symbols so if you are running on your local machine you can now get gdb support!

It's a bit of a process and ripe for some more automation (suggestions welcome)

in short:

1. look for the _app_go process
2. cd to the directory that it's running from
3. Attach to the process with the '-pid' command to gdb
4. Tell gdb the directory of source

Boom -- debugging.

Comment: It works, kind of.

Even if I use the --max_module_instances to keep the number of instances down, the instance changes PID so fast so that it is impossible to debug. Have you found any solution to this?

Comment: No great solution -- I was half working on a script to automate this but nothing yet....  It's kind of sad compared to how strong the tools for python on app engine are.